# Sync Flash Drive OS with Virtual

Tags: usb-drive, virtualization, sync

I have installed ubuntu (Lubuntu 14.04 specifically, but I don't think that matters for this question) to a USB flash drive (full install, not live system) so I can have an ubuntu environment I can take with me anywhere. I use it for development on a project I am working on. I would like to copy the flash drive's partitions to virtual disks and run them from virtualbox when I am at home, both to take advantage of the speed of my desktop and to minimize wear on the flash media.

**My question is when I go back on the road, how do I sync the changes (both project contents and OS changes) back to the flash drives partitions?**

I would really like to avoid having to recopy whole partitions each time. I was thinking of booting virtualbox to a live environment and then using something like rsync. Would that work and would the files be copied correctly (permissions, etc.). I don't know much about rsync. What kind of command would I need.

*Bonus question: Any recommendations as to the best way to initially create the virtual disk files?*

I was thinking again of booting into a live environment but for this initial time using something like gparted to copy the partitions in tact. That way the UUIDs match so fstab can stay the same.